# Arithmetical progression vs. Functions

Tags: functions, arithmetic-progressions

I have been studying a lot of Maths recently but I am still in the fundamentals. Although I don't work directly with some topics, I find it very interesting.

Anyways, I was studying arithmetical progression and although I understood the definition as well as the concept, something puzzles me: When do I use **arithmetical progression** instead of **functions**? You see, if we take a *linear function*, it seems a lot like an arithmetical progression, or it is something from my mind? Maybe I lack in experience and I am misunderstanding some concepts.

To illustrate my question lets tackle this problem both using PA and function:

*"A guy wants to buy a car whose price is $10.000$. He has saved $4800$ already and he is gonna save $1.200 monthly. How long is it gonna take for him to collect this amount?"*

By function:
   $f(x) = 1200x + 0$
   and we solve for x being $$5200

By PA we simply start at $4800$ and find $N $

As you can see... both ways are possible. So please, when do I use one instead of another?

Thanks in advance
Cheers from Brazil

Comment: Arithmetic progressions deal with discrete inputs, namely the integers, whereas functions (typically linear) are continuous. You might find arithmetic progressions used more in computer science, where it might not always be easier to deal with a continuous function.

Comment: Also, there are forms you deal with in arithmetic progressions that can't be expressed in continuous functions, namely, recursively defined formulas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...but lemme ask you one thing: Is a PA a Linear function? Or I cant say that?

Comment: PA is very similar to a linear function, but it is not a linear function. Remember that you are only getting paid every month, not continuously. Since I can't decide to get $\$400$ after a third of a month (I can only get my money in $\$1200$ chunks every month, this is not continuous, and is most effectively modeled as an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Nice, now I understand the concept! Thanks for your time and consideration @Hyperion! You are the best ;P

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic progressions, are outputs of a linear function, evaluated at the integer values. This is only a subset of all the values the linear function takes on.

The equation to solve would be 10000=1200x+4800 where x is in months, not dollar dollars. This equation simplifies to 5200=1200x. x is then 4.25 which will be rounded up to the nearest integer to become 5.